# Python/Pandas Write File Line by Line :: Memory Use

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame loaded into memory with Pandas (~9GB). I am trying to write out a text file that follows a given format (Vowpal Wabbit) and am confused about the memory usage and performance. While the file is large (48 million rows) the initial load into Pandas is not bad. Writing out the file takes at least 6+ hours and literally crushes my laptop and consumed nearly every bit of my RAM (32GB). Naively, I assumed this operation was operating on one line at a time and so the RAM use would be very small. Is there a more efficient way to process this data?

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\DATA\\train_mobile2.vw", "wb") as outfile:
    for index, row in train.iterrows():
        if row['click'] ==0:
            vwline=""
            vwline+="-1 "
        else:
            vwline=""
            vwline+="1 "
        vwline+="|a C1_"+ str(row['C1']) +\
        " |b banpos_"+ str(row['banner_pos']) +\
        " |c siteid_"+ str(row['site_id']) +\
        " sitedom_"+ str(row['site_domain']) +\
        " sitecat_"+ str(row['site_category']) +\
        " |d appid_"+ str(row['app_id']) +\
        " app_domain_"+ str(row['app_domain']) +\
        " app_cat_"+ str(row['app_category']) +\
        " |e d_id_"+ str(row['device_id']) +\
        " d_ip_"+ str(row['device_ip']) +\
        " d_os_"+ str(row['device_os']) +\
        " d_make_"+ str(row['device_make']) +\
        " d_mod_"+ str(row['device_model']) +\
        " d_type_"+ str(row['device_type']) +\
        " d_conn_"+ str(row['device_conn_type']) +\
        " d_geo_"+ str(row['device_geo_country']) +\
        " |f num_a:"+ str(row['C17']) +\
        " numb:"+ str(row['C18']) +\
        " numc:"+ str(row['C19']) +\
        " numd:"+ str(row['C20']) +\
        " nume:"+ str(row['C22']) +\
        " numf:"+ str(row['C24']) +\
        " |g c21_"+ str(row['C21']) +\
        " C23_"+ str(row['C23']) +\
        " |h hh_"+ str(row['hh']) +\
        " |i doe_"+ str(row['doe']) 
        outfile.write(vwline + "\n")
```

In response to the suggestion from User,

I coded the following but am getting an error when the last line it ran that says "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'"

```
lines_T = np.where(train['click'] == 0, "-1 ", "1 ") +\
        "|a C1_" + train['C1'].astype('str') +\
        " |b banpos_"+ train['banner_pos'].astype('str') +\
....

        "|h hh_"+ train['hh'].astype('str')+\
        " |i doe_"+ train['doe'].astype('str')    #ERROR HERE
```

line_T.to_csv("C:\Users\Desktop\DATA\KAGGLE\mobile\train_mobile.vw",mode='a', header=False,index=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the memory usage, but this should definitely be faster:

```
lines = np.where(train['click'] == 0, "-1 ", "1 ") +
        "|a C1_" + train['C1'].astype('str') +
        " |b banpos_"+ train['banner_pos'].astype('str') +
        ...
```

and then save the lines

```
lines.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
```

You can also do it in batches (say a few million records at time) if memory becomes an issue

Comment: Is using iterrows() known to be inefficient?

Comment: In general vectorized operations are faster as they are highly optimized. Iterrows slower but I would be surprised if that is the cause of your memory blowup

Comment: I recoded this, but am getting an error on the last line - I will add to the question above.

Comment: Needed to wrap the np.where() with pd.Series() as in pd.Series(np.where(...)) it seems